# Playing Youtubes with HTML 5 on iOS

Tags: ios, html, youtube, html5-video

I am trying load a YouTube video into a HTML 5  tag.
The problem I am having is I do not know what the “src” property should be. Using the URL for a video on YouTube does not seem to work, that URL seems to retrieve an entire page rather than just a video file.
I have been able to copy and paste YouTube’s own  tag (by viewing the page source), that they use on their pages, but this is not a very efficient or long term solution.  Is there a better solution?
I have tried to use YouTube’s API, but no matter what I do, it seems always to pull in the flash player version of the player (which of course won’t work for iOS.) Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 1):

This blog post might help: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html

The suggestion is to use this code:

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385"
        src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

The iframe will autodetect HTML5 capabilities and use them; if not, it uses Flash as fallback.